# Discord.py app_commands | Multiple arguments for function

Tags: python, discord.py

I want to setup an `app_command` function which can take unlimited arguments.

Example code with unlimited arguments:

```
def example(*arg: str):
    # instert code
```

Example code where I want unlimited of amount `discord.Role`:

```
@bot.tree.command(name='example')
async def example(interaction: discord.Interaction, roles: discord.Role):
    # instert code
```

How can I achieve this (if this is achivable)?

> If I try `*roles: discord.Role`, I´ll get this Error:
>
> TypeError: unsupported parameter kind in callback: VAR_POSITIONAL